# characteristics of rings (2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Below are a few propositions, most of which most likely only require short, fairly easy proofs.

1. Prove that every unital ring of characteristic zero is infinite.
2. Is an example of an infinite ring of characteristic 10 the infinite Cartesian product of the set of integers modulo 10?
3. Prove that every integral domain has characteristic zero or p, where p is prime.

Here's what I've come up with so far (I apologize if some of it is unclear due to my lack of understanding):

1) Let $R$ be a unital ring of characteristic zero. Assume $R$ is finite. By assumption, we can write $R$ as $R = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ...,a_{n}),$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is finite. Since $R$ is unital, we may assume without loss of generality that $a_{1} = 1$. Since $R$ is of characteristic $0$, then $\not\exists n\in \mathbb{N} 
\space(n\cdot 1 = 0)$. $1\neq 0$ in $R$. I'm stuck here. I know I should show that there exists another element in $R$, thus contradicting the finiteness of $R$ and proving that it is infinite. But I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $R$ is a group under addition. Recall that if $G$ is a group and $m$ is the order of $G$, then $g^m$ is the identity for all $g \in G$. Alternatively, since $R$ is finite there exist distinct $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \cdot 1 = n \cdot 1$ (or else $\{m \cdot 1 : m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite). Then $(m - n) \cdot 1 = 0$.

2) Yes.

3) Suppose $I$ is an integral domain of composite characteristic $n$. Then $n = ab$ for positive integers $a,b$ with $a,b < n$. For $m \in \mathbb{N}$ let $m_I$ denote the element of $I$ obtained by adding the multiplicative identity to itself $m$ times. Show that $a_I,b_I \neq 0$ and $a_I \cdot b_I = 0$. The key here is to check that $(ab)_I = a_I \cdot b_I$, where $ab$ denotes the product of the integers $a$ and $b$ and $\cdot$ is multiplication in $I$.